# Text file editing and line writing

Tags: python, text-files

I have a slight problem with my code.

First the code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import httplib, urllib

for ip in range(1,255):

   ip_addr = "192.168.1." + str(ip)
   res = subprocess.call(["ping", ip_addr, "-c1", "-W1", "-q"], stdout=open(os.devnull,'w'))
   if res == 0:
      print (ip_addr) + " reachable"
   else:
      print (ip_addr) + " not reachable"

   f = open('state_All.txt','r')
   prestate = f.readline(ip)
   f.close()
   prestate = ord(prestate)
   res = res + 97
   if not prestate == res:
      if prestate == 97:
         conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.pushover.net:443")
         ## The Code in here which I have deleted out is definitely not the problem,
         ## works 100% safe and can't be share beacuse of security problems.
          }), { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
         conn.getresponse()
      else:
         conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.pushover.net:443")
         ## The Code in here which I have deleted out is definitely not the problem,
         ## works 100% safe and can't be share beacuse of security problems.
          }), { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
         conn.getresponse()
   f = open('state_All.txt','w')
   res = str(unichr(res))
   data = (res[ip])
   f.writelines(data)
   f.close()
```

Problem:

Reading some specific lines in the .txt works but I can't write on a specific line the measured state afterwards,

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ping_All.py", line 48, in <module>
    data = (res[ip])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Hope someone can help me with it.

Comment: It looks like the string `res` is not up to 255 characters long... why are you using `ip` as your string index? The operation on line 48 that throws the error is trying to access a character in your string, but your string isn't long enough.

Answer (score 0):

When you try access an item from that string, you get `index out of range`. This means that you tried to access an item, in your case a Character, where the index (`ip`) was either larger than the length of `res` or smaller than 0.